# String to dict with duplicates

Tags: python

I think I am missing something basic here. I was trying to split a string into a dict with key as the index and value as the character.

```
instring = 'aabc'
stringmap = {instring.index(i): i for i in instring}

When I print stringmap: {0: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

I was expecting

```
{0: 'a', 1: 'a', 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
```

What am I missing? The index values are right, but the duplicates are not part of the dict.

Comment: Use the [```enumerate()```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function to index an array.

Comment: `dict(enumerate("aabc"))`

Comment: Or `{ num: instring[num] for num in range(len(instring)) }`

Comment: The problem with you method is that `index` only finds the first occurrence of the substring being searched for. Thus, even though you search for `a` twice, both times it returns `0`.

Comment: But, what is wrong with what I am doing? I would like to understand that and not fix this and move on. I definitely am not understanding something right.

Comment: ```list.index()``` returns the first occurence of item in the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `index(i)` method always returns the index of the first occurrence.  That's why you get duplicate keys (i.e. zero for both instances of the letter `a`).

Simply feeding enumerate to the dict constructor will do the trick:

```
stringmap = dict(enumerate(instring))
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey @sam You can solve your problem with this.

```
string = "sohaib"

{index:i for index,i in enumerate(string)}
```

**Answer**

```
{0: 's', 1: 'o', 2: 'h', 3: 'a', 4: 'i', 5: 'b'}
```